# Making my character talk with a speechbubble using 2 actionscript3 (info below)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, click, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I've been taking a computer programming class for high school and I've been stuck on this problem for longer than I'd like to admit. I'm in a program that basically sets it up so you work at your own pace with a teacher and no classmates that know what I'm doing so basically I'm teaching myself to some extent.

Okay so my job is to make a speech bubble I made pop up when I click on my character using the script I made for my character (Shippo.as) and the speech bubble made this activity for assignment 1 (SpeechBubble.as).

So far when I run the program my character pops up, but when I click on him nothing happens. I get no errors or anything so the problem is with the code but I'm unable to spot it. I will display the codes for everything below by the names I'm using for them to hand in.

**- U1A6As2 - Talking Character**

```
import Shippo;
import SpeechBubble;

var shippo_mc:Shippo = new Shippo;
addChild(shippo_mc);

shippo_mc.x = 250;
shippo_mc.y = 200;
```

(this code creates and displays my character named Shippo.)

**- SpeechBubble.as**

```
package
{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import mc_SpeechBubble;
   import Shippo;

      public class SpeechBubble extends MovieClip
      {
       public function SpeechBubble (xPosition:Number, yPosition:Number, message:String)
           {
                var bubble_mc:MovieClip = new mc_SpeechBubble();
                bubble_mc.x = xPosition;
                bubble_mc.y = yPosition;
                bubble_mc.speechText_txt.text = message;
        addChild(bubble_mc);
           }

      }
}
```

(This code is from the tutorial from Activity 6, Assignment 1, the only thing I added was *import Shippo;*)

**- Shippo.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import mc_SpeechBubble;
    import SpeechBubble;

    public class Shippo extends MovieClip
    {

        public function Shippo()
        {
            trace ("Click me and I'll talk.");
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shippoTalk);
        }

        public function shippoTalk(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var bubble:SpeechBubble = new SpeechBubble(350,50,"Hello, my  
                        name's Shippo.");
            addChild(bubble);
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shippoTalk);
        }
    }   
}
```

(The only reason the *trace ("Click me and I'll talk.");* is in the code is just so I know that part is working correctly, it's not needed. I think the problem lies in the *shippoTalk function* but not sure how to fix it because the code in *shippoTalk* is the one used during assignment 1 of activity 6.)

Keep in mind I'm no flash pro and I don't know the language to well so bear with me, I'm trying to stick with what I have learned and not go to far off the rails but in all honesty as long as this gets done I will be happy, any help will be good help.

Answer (score 1):

You've mis-spelled 'function' as 'funtion' in your mc_SpeechBubble constructor method.

Also f.y.i., you don't have to use most of your 'import' statements if your classes are all in the same package.

Comment: Sadly that's not the problem that was a mistake I made when typing it on here, it's fine in the actual code. I will fix it on here though. And thanks for the info on the imports, right now I need to use two classes for this lesson to make the project work. Thanks for the help.